# Removing objects whose counts are less than threshold in counter

Tags: python

I have a counter declared as: `main_dict = Counter()` and values are added as `main_dict[word] += 1`. In the end I want to remove all the elements less than 15 in frequency. Is there any function in `Counter` to do this?

Answer (score 32):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15, 'foo': 10})
>>> Counter({k: c for k, c in counter.items() if c >= 15})
Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15})
```

Comment: In python 3 I get "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"

Comment: @Ferran You were right, updated to be both Py2/Py3 compatible

Comment: The repeated use of `c` in the dict comprehension is confusing - is it necessary, or can this safely be rewritten as: `Counter({k: cc for k, cc in c.items() if cc >= 15})` ?

Comment: @jtlz2 you were right so I just changed the first `c` to `counter`

Answer (score 23):

No, you'll need to remove them manually. Using `itertools.dropwhile()` makes that a little easier perhaps:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

for key, count in dropwhile(lambda key_count: key_count[1] >= 15, main_dict.most_common()):
    del main_dict[key]
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> main_dict
Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15, 'foo': 10})
>>> for key, count in dropwhile(lambda key_count: key_count[1] >= 15, main_dict.most_common()):
...     del main_dict[key]
... 
>>> main_dict
Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15})
```

By using `dropwhile` you only need to test the keys for which the count is 15 or over; after that it'll forgo testing and just pass through everything. That works great with the sorted `most_common()` list. If there are a lot of values below 15, that saves execution time for all those tests.

Comment: Also `'bar'` shouldn't be deleted since its frequency is not less than 15. Actually this idea may work in a different way, but not really for deleting keys. eg. `new_dict = dict(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] >= 15, main_dict.most_common()))`

Comment: @jamylak: `dropwhile` stops testing once it stops matching; for a large number of keys that makes a difference. I'll investigate the error later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But that doesn't matter since you are already storing the whole `.most_common()` list into memory first

Comment: @jamylak: you have to *at least* store all the keys in memory, since we are altering the dictionary. Fixed the error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You still have to iterate through every single key though

Comment: @jamylak: The `dropwhile` stops *testing* the values, I never said it won't loop through all the keys. It'll only test values until you no longer match the predicate, after which it just loops. If there are a lot of keys below the 15 threshold, that makes a difference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok but `.most_common()` would have to do a sort, which is O(N log N), just iterating through and checking if condition is O(N).

Comment: @MartijnPieters refer here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l451 it has to do `sorted` first, it's not maintained as sorted

Comment: Yup, `.most_common()` will do a straight sort.

Comment: I am still 100% that the `dropwhile` + `most_common` combo is completely useless and has an O(N log N) runtime as opposed to my naive solution which is O(N)

Comment: @jamylak: sure. Why, after more than a year, reiterate that comment? :-)

Comment: Now after a couple of years, is `dropwhile` + `most_common` useful or just iterate through and `del` keys better?

Answer (score 17):

Another method:

```
c = Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15, 'foo': 10})
print Counter(el for el in c.elements() if c[el] >= 15)
# Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15})
```

Comment: Why `.elements()` over `.items()`, the latter would be faster

Comment: @jamylak Because `.items` returns a tuple and when passed back to `Counter` ends up with  a tuple of the key/value pairs with a value of `1` (I think - blame late night and pub lunch)

Comment: Alright, or you could also do this: `Counter({k: c for k, c in c.items() if c >= 15})`

Answer (score 2):

may I suggest another solution

```
from collections import Counter
main_dict = Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15, 'foo': 10})  
trsh = 15

main_dict = Counter(dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] >= trsh, main_dict.items())))
print(main_dict)

>>> Counter({'baz': 20, 'bar': 15})
```

Also I have the same problem, but I need to return a list of all keys from Counter with values more than some threshold. To do this

```
keys_list = map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] >= trsh, main_dict.items()))
print(keys_list) 

>>> ['baz', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution when **the threshold is zero**:

```
main_dict += Counter()
```

Comment: `Counter` is `dict` for counting, when 2 `Counter`s are added together, the result's keys are also removed if their value is 0. I wouldn't use this trick in my code, but it's elegant.

Comment: In this case, unary addition works too: `main_dict = +main_dict`.

Answer (score 2):

An example of how to filter items whoso count greater than or less than a threshold in counter

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile


data = (
    "Here's a little song about Roy G. Biv. "
    "He makes up all the colors that you see where you live. "
    "If you know all the colors, sing them with me: "
    "red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet all that you see."
)

c = Counter(data)

more_than_10 = dict(takewhile(lambda i: i[1] > 10, c.most_common()))
less_than_2 = dict(dropwhile(lambda i: i[1] >= 2, c.most_common()))

print(f"> 10 {more_than_10} \n2 < {less_than_2}")
```

Output:

```
> 10 {' ': 40, 'e': 23, 'o': 16, 'l': 15, 't': 12} 
2 < {"'": 1, 'R': 1, 'G': 1, 'B': 1, 'p': 1, 'I': 1, 'f': 1, ':': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a list comprehension of dictionary items:

```
[el for el in c.items() if el[1] >= 15]
```